# Prove that for every set $A$, $B$, and $C$, $^{A}(B\times C)\sim\,^{A}B\times^{A}C$. Is my proof correct?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, proof-writing

This is the problem from "How to Prove It. A Structured Approach" by Danile. J. Velleman.

For any sets $A$ and $B$, the set of all functions from $A$ to $B$ is denoted  $^{A}B$.

$A \sim B$ denotes equinumerous sets (there is one-to-one and onto function from $A$ to $B$).

That's my proof.

Let $g:B\times C \to B$ be defined by the formula $g(x,y) = x$, and $h:B\times C \to C$ be defined by the formula $h(x,y) = y$. So lets define the function $F:^{A}(B\times C) \to\, ^{A}B\times ^{A}C$ by the formula $F(f) = (g\circ f, h\circ f)$. Now we should check that $F$ is one-to-one and onto.

1. **Is $F$ one-to-one?** Let $f_1,f_2 \in\, ^{A}(B\times C)$ and $F(f_1) = F(f_2)$. Our goal is to prove that $f_1 = f_2$. So we have $(g\circ f_1, h\circ f_1) = (g\circ f_2, h\circ f_2)$, and then $g\circ f_1 = g\circ f_2$, $h\circ f_1 = h\circ f_2$. Let $(x, (y,z)) \in f_1$, so $(x,y) \in g\circ f_1$, and then $(x,y) \in g\circ f_2$. Since $(x,y)\in g\circ f_2$ there is some $z'\in C$ so that $g(y,z') = y$ and $f_2(x) = (y,z')$. On the other hand $(x,z) \in h\circ f_1$ and then $(x,z)\in h\circ f_2$. So there is $y' \in B$, $h(y', z) = z$ and $f(x) = (y',z)$. Finally, we have $f(x) = (y,z')$ and $f(x) = (y', z)$, so $(y,z') = (y',z)$ and then $y = y'$, $z = z'$. So $(x, (y,z)) \in f_2$ and $f_1 \subseteq f_2$. In other direction the proof is similar. So $f_1 = f_2$.
2. **Is F onto?** Let $(f_1, f_2) \in\, ^{A}B\times ^{A}C$. We should check, that there is a function $f \in\,^{A}(B\times C)$ so that $F(f) = (f_1,f_2)$. Lets define function $f:A\to B\times C$ by the formula $f(x) = (f_1(x), f_2(x))$. Since $F(f) = (g\circ f, h\circ f)$ let's consider $(g\circ f)(x) = g(f(x)) = g(f_1(x), f_2(x)) = f_1(x)$. So $g\circ f = f_1$. Similarly $h\circ f = f_2$, so $F(f) = (f_1, f_2)$. And we can conclude that $F$ is onto.

Comment: This is not a "check-my-proof" site. The `solution-verification` informs you that the post is only on topic if there is a *specific* step that you are unsure of/unclear on, and you must specify this step explicitly and explain explicitly the reason you are unsure or unclear. Otherwise, the question lacks focus and is off-topic.